# I have applied encryption on string values. But how can we implement on integer values?

Tags: java, encryption, aes

How can we make changes to support integer values in java?

Current Encryption/Decryption at String values:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_ENCRYPTION_SCHEME);
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getSecretKeyAES(secret));
return Base64.encodeBase64String(cipher.doFinal(plaintext.getBytes("UTF-8")));

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_ENCRYPTION_SCHEME);
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, getSecretKeyAES(secret));
return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(ciphertext)));
```

Comment: Just like you call `getBytes()` on a string, you should convert the integers to bytes.  One way to do this would be to use a `DataOutputStream` which would allow you convert most any type to bytes.

Comment: I can think of two other ways: a) make it simple and turn the integers into string and b) `byteBuffer.putInt(n)` and then encrypt `byteBuffer.array()`